# Reading and appending data from files to a list in parallel using python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to read in several files, and append certain elements from them to a list. reading the files seems to be slow, so I thought `multiprocessing` might be able to help me with that. I produced the following code to do what I wanted, essentially in parallel open the numbered `file_%i`, and pull out the relevant data `read_append` and append it to a `global` array `res = manager.list()` that is shared between processes. sample code given below. However, this fails to work. attempting to print `a.shape`  gives the error message included below the sample code. I am not quite sure how to fix this errant code, and am quite new to `multiprocessing`. I suspect, this hacky script that i put together using SO answers and the man pages for multiprocessing is far from ideal.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
def read_append(input_list):
    val, res_arr = input_list
    data_file = np.load('file_%i.npz' %val, mmap_mode = 'r', allow_pickle=True)['data']
    for i in range(len(data_file)):
        res_arr.append(data_file[i][1])
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    N= mp.cpu_count()
    print(N)
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        res = manager.list()
        input_list = [(val, res) for val in range(2)]
        with mp.Pool(processes = N) as p:
            results = p.map(read_append,input_list)
end = timer()
print(end-start)
a = list(res)
print(a.shape)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py in _callmethod(self, methodname, args, kwds)
    810         try:
--> 811             conn = self._tls.connection
    812         except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-35028af51086> in <module>
     21 end = timer()
     22 print(end-start)
---> 23 a = list(res)
     24 print(a.shape)

<string> in __len__(self, *args, **kwds)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py in _callmethod(self, methodname, args, kwds)
    813             util.debug('thread %r does not own a connection',
    814                        threading.current_thread().name)
--> 815             self._connect()
    816             conn = self._tls.connection
    817 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/managers.py in _connect(self)
    800         if threading.current_thread().name != 'MainThread':
    801             name += '|' + threading.current_thread().name
--> 802         conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
    803         dispatch(conn, None, 'accept_connection', (name,))
    804         self._tls.connection = conn

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py in Client(address, family, authkey)
    490         c = PipeClient(address)
    491     else:
--> 492         c = SocketClient(address)
    493 
    494     if authkey is not None and not isinstance(authkey, bytes):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py in SocketClient(address)
    617     with socket.socket( getattr(socket, family) ) as s:
    618         s.setblocking(True)
--> 619         s.connect(address)
    620         return Connection(s.detach())
    621 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think `res` is a `global` variable, why do you assume it so?
2. A list does not have an attribute `shape`, numpy arrays do.
3. You are trying to access the managed list `res` after closing the
   manager process in which the list resides. So you need to shift the
   code where you use `res` inside the `with mp.Manager() as manager`
   block:
4. Your timer isn't actually measuring anything useful except in the
   main process. In the child processes it is actually measuring the
   time needed to import libraries and define functions. You should
   consider shifting it inside main. If you want to time how much time
   each function takes, then start the timer inside the function and
   return `end-start`:

**Example fixed code:**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer


def read_append(input_list):
    val, res_arr = input_list
    data_file = np.load('file_%i.npz' %val, mmap_mode = 'r', allow_pickle=True)['data']
    for i in range(len(data_file)):
        res_arr.append(data_file[i][1])
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = timer()
    N= mp.cpu_count()
    print(N)
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        res = manager.list()
        input_list = [(val, res) for val in range(2)]
        with mp.Pool(processes = N) as p:
            results = p.map(read_append,input_list)
        a = np.array(res)
        print(a.shape)
    end = timer()
    print(end - start)
```

Comment: thanks. I guess I see my mistake now. the variable `res` is not global but local to the context of the `with` statement. Could I have initialized between `def read_append()` and `if __name__ == '__main__':`. would that be considered a global variable and be accessible to the processes working in pool?

Comment: @jcp That would be a global variable and accessible within the function only if use `global res` inside. Moreover, if you are thinking that `res` will contain the managed list you create inside the `if __name__...` block then that is incorrect. That block only runs in the main process and not the child processes. Child and parent processes do not share memory.